# как перенаправять с роутов laravel пользователя на роуты vue-router?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

есть проект на laravel 8 где фронт написан на vue 3. на фронте когда пользователь переходит по путям с помощью `router-link`, `router-view` загружаются и показывают компоненты. к примеру если через `router-link` пользователь переходит на `/overview/12`, `router-view` загружает свой компонент, **но** когда пользователь находится по этому же пути и перезагружает страницу то выводится `laravel`-ий шаблон страницы ошибки `404` мол такого роута нет. 
как сделать чтобы все роуты кроме `/api/*`(туда я делаю запросы RESTapi) делали переходы с помощью `vue-router`.
`resorces/js/router/index.js`:

```
import IndexSlider from "../components/IndexSlider";
import Newsfeed from "../views/Newsfeed";
import Overview from "../views/Overview";

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'index',
        redirect: '/index'
    },
    {
        path: '/index',
        name: 'index-slider',
        component: IndexSlider,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'newsfeed',
                name: 'newsfeed',
                component: Newsfeed
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '/overview/:id',
        name: 'overview',
        component: Overview,
        props: true
    }

]

export default routes;
```

`web/web.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\IndexController;


Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

так я пытался делать этот редирект, но в консоли показывалась такая ошибка
[image: chrome console]
[image: chrome console]

`/routes/api.php`: эти роуты должны работать дла запросов `axios`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\NewsController;

Route::resource('news', NewsController::class);
```

`vue@3.0.5`, `vue-router@4.0.3`, `laravel 8`

Comment: А что мешает перенаправить все роуты? `Route::view('/{any}', 'welcome')->where('any', '.*');` а все апи маршруты обрабатывать через routes/api

Comment: @Walfter появляется ошибка с картинок. он загружается index.blade.php но не как html страницу а как js чтоли. иначе почему такая ошибка

Answer (score -1, accepted):

проблема во вложенности путей. просто подключение скриптов в `index.blade.php` изменить на `/js/app.js` и все в шакаладе. лучше воспользоваться `asset()`

Comment: Эм=))) А зачем вы вышли два раза из папки? Что у вас за маршрут? Может стоит указать один путь постоянный? Или относительно корня хотя бы?

Comment: @Walfter неправильно переписал. спасибо. поправил